# last value carried forward in pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I have 20 minutes of observed data, in 5 minute bins as follows:

```
  bin   var1    var2    var3    var4
    5   -76.30  71.96   557.79  0.06
    10  -61.23  78.14   600.69  0.09
    15  -54.36  73.63   630.71  0.03
    20  -12.41  71.46   661.19  0.08
```

I need to model for an hour of data by carrying the last observed value forward and get the following output:

```
bin var1    var2    var3    var4
5   -76.30  71.96   557.79  0.06
10  -61.23  78.14   600.69  0.03
15  -54.36  73.63   630.71  0.09
20  -12.41  71.46   661.19  0.08
25  -12.41  71.46   661.19  0.08
30  -12.41  71.46   661.19  0.08
35  -12.41  71.46   661.19  0.08
40  -12.41  71.46   661.19  0.08
45  -12.41  71.46   661.19  0.08
50  -12.41  71.46   661.19  0.08
55  -12.41  71.46   661.19  0.08
60  -12.41  71.46   661.19  0.08
```

what is the best way to code this in a pandas data frame? please & thanks.

Comment: Not a very interesting "model"!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

While you can append to the DataFrame, it's a relatively inefficient operation, as each step takes a copy.  [`reindex`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/basics.html#reindexing-and-altering-labels) provides an easy way to align the data to a new index, then you can forward fill the the values with `fillna` method.

```
In [31]: df = df.set_index('bin')
    ...: df = df.reindex(range(5, 65, 5)).fillna(method='ffill')


In [32]: df
Out[32]: 
      var1   var2    var3  var4
bin                            
5   -76.30  71.96  557.79  0.06
10  -61.23  78.14  600.69  0.09
15  -54.36  73.63  630.71  0.03
20  -12.41  71.46  661.19  0.08
25  -12.41  71.46  661.19  0.08
30  -12.41  71.46  661.19  0.08
35  -12.41  71.46  661.19  0.08
40  -12.41  71.46  661.19  0.08
45  -12.41  71.46  661.19  0.08
50  -12.41  71.46  661.19  0.08
55  -12.41  71.46  661.19  0.08
60  -12.41  71.46  661.19  0.08
```

Comment: any idea how I can put _bin_ back to normal column and set a new index?  this did solve my initial problem, but it is now affecting plotting :(

Comment: `df = df.reset_index()`

Answer (score 0):

You could append row `i` (in your case, `i == 3`) `j` times (`j == 8`) with

```
bin = df.iloc[i].copy()  # to avoid modifying the original dataframe
for _ in range(j):
    bin['bin'] += 5 
    df = df.append(bin, ignore_index=True)
```

`df` refers to your `pandas.DataFrame` object.

Comment: thanks for this! it worked, except for the new values in the _bin_ column all being '20'. @chrisb's suggestion below seems to take care of that problem.

Comment: I've edited my post to fix the _bin_ column. [@chrisb's](http://stackoverflow.com/users/3657742/chrisb) version is indeed superior in performance. If however the only bottleneck is your level of comfort with python my version might be easier to reproduce in another context.

Comment: great! thanks. will try both and see which works best for my purpose - especially since I'm having to reindex with @chrisb's suggestion in order to plot against original data